# How to user resValue in String resource file

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources

I have defined a property in my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and I want to access it in a string resources file.

**Definition in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`**
`ServerIP="XXX.XXX.XX.XX"`

**Declaration in `app/build.gradle`**

```
android {  
  buildTypes.each {  
    it.resValue "string", "ServerIP", "SERVER_IP"
  }
}
```

**Usage in `string/web_services.xml`**
`<string name="serverIP">@string/SERVER_IP</string>`

**Error during build**
`Error:(4, 5) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'serverIP' with value '@string/SERVER_IP').`

Is there any way to achieve this or it can't be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
it.resValue "string", "ServerIP", "SERVER_IP"
```

The first argument is type, the second is name and the third is value. In your case name should be `"SERVER_IP"` and value should be `ServerIP` without quotes. So final piece in `build.gradle`:

```
android {  
  buildTypes.each {  
    it.resValue "string", "SERVER_IP", ServerIP
  }
}
```